# Problem, when selecting points, the segment itself is not selected

Tags: modeling

Problem, when selecting points, the segment itself is not selected

[image]

what happens

[image]

what I need

Comment: Try Face Select

Comment: can you tell me how please, it's just that I'm still quite new to blender

Comment: By default, hit 1, 2, or 3 on the keyboard (not numpad) for vertex, edge, or face selection, respectively.

Comment: If you mean that the face is not selected, there must be a problem like overlapping vertices, please share your file (just the part with the problem): https://blend-exchange.com/